# Datetime string with timezone in Python?

Tags: python, timezone

I'm working on Google app engine with Python.

I have stored a datetime object in database and fetched it and applied timezone, and I saved it using template. The result is `"2011-03-15 16:54:24.398503+09:00"`, but what I want is: `"2011-03-16 01:54:24"` (timezone applied string without millisecond - note that day is changed).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the datetime object, use strftime, like so;

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Does strftime apply timezone? I just tried but it seems localtime is not applied. I get "2011-03-15 16:54:24" instead of "2011-03-16 01:54:24"

Comment: datetime.now() *is* localtime.
datetime.utcnow() returns the UTC compliant form.

strftime just specifies the partial output from that datetime object.
If you need a specific region timezone you should do something like,

import pytz

datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Africa/Casablanca')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Answer (score 0):

using strftime is encouraged, but make sure that your localtime is correct. This should be a setting in your app/site assuming you're using django, or you may have to do this manually

Comment: Yes I'm using django. But what do you mean by localtime is correct?

Comment: by default the timezone is chicago, there's a line in settings.py where you can set your timezone